# How can I add value to ArrayList in class x while the making object of class x in the main class

Tags: java, arraylist

In the main class I want to make an object of ChainOfItems class in the meanwhile fill the Arraylist as well. I can fill it with null value but with numbers I cannot do it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ChainOfItems {
    private ArrayList<Integer> itemes= new ArrayList<>();

    public Chain() {
    }

    public Chain(ArrayList<Integer> itemes) {
        super();
        this.itemes = itemes;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getRequiredVNFTypes() {
        return itemes;
    }

    public void setitemes(ArrayList<Integer> itemes) {
        this.itemes = itemes;
    }   
}

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChainOfItems item1=new ChainOfItems(null);///what i want to say the list contains two variable 1 and 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> items= new ArrayList<>();
items.add(1);
items.add(10);
ChainOfItems item1=new ChainOfItems(items);
```

Above should work for you.

It is much better to use interfaces instead of given implementation (read about [OOP concepts](https://raygun.com/blog/oop-concepts-java/)). Consider to change class in this way:

```
public class ChainOfItems {
    private List<Integer> items;

    public Chain() {
        this(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public Chain(ArrayList<Integer> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public List<Integer> getRequiredVNFTypes() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<Integer> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }   
}
```

Now you can provide many implementations of `List` interface:

```
ChainOfItems item1=new ChainOfItems(Arrays.asList(1,10));
```

or

```
List<Integer> items= new LinkedList<>();
items.add(1);
items.add(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor and the setitemes (spelling) method accepts an ArrayList.

```
item1.setitemes(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1, 10)));
```

Or:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(10);
item.setitemes(list);
```